# When closing a New Question as an Exact Duplicate

Tags: discussion

When closing a New Question as an Exact Duplicate as so...

closed as exact duplicate by LessPop_MoreFizz, yx., Raven Dreamer♦ 12 hours ago

This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question. See the FAQ

To me it would make sense to include a link to the Earlier Accepted Question instead of leaving the new ask-er in limbo. adding the link would be helpful and in no way detrimental.
I completely agree with thinning Duplicate questions but think making it
Standard Procedure in including the Accepted Question link in the closed statement...

I humbly ask this here hoping this is the right forum and hoping this discussion leads
to the addition i described.

I look forward to all answers and comments,thank you in advance.

the names listed in the copied closing statement i used is an actual one and i chose
it because i have come to respect those listed, i hope this was ok : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about this question: [Can you not do the bucket trick on Xbox?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43096/can-you-not-do-the-bucket-trick-on-xbox) . A link to the duplicate question is indicated at the top of the question:

[image]

This is true for all Closed as Duplicate questions, unless someone manually edited it out.

Comment: i just used the closed statement as an example,a lot i have seen closed didn't include the link like you showed,which is why i posed the question. i wasn't sure if this was SOP or not.

Comment: @Master69Wraith No, *all* questions that are closed as duplicates have that link on top, unless, as I've said, someone edited it out. It would be helpful if you could actually point to examples of questions without those links.

Comment: ok thank you,then this happily answers my question. must have been the edited ones i remember seeing then. Thank you very much : )